# How to get an AngularJS controller in a filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to use dependency injection to reference a controller inside of a filter?  I tried the following:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function(MyCtrl) {...})
app.controller('MyCtrl', function(...) {})
```

But I get an error that MyCtrl dependency cannot be found.

Comment: If you need to expose anything from the controller, make it a service instead and inject it both on the controller and the service using DI..

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This isn't something you should need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access some sort of state information inside your filter, you should consider moving that functionality into a service and then accessing the service from both your filter and your controller.

I can't come up with a reason to want to instantiate a controller inside a filter, so perhaps if you gave a bit more background about the problem you are trying to solve we could give you more tailored information on how best to implement it.

In any case, [here's a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6duhFQ?p=preview) showing a filter and a controller sharing some data:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.text = "ABCDEFG";
  $scope.data = 2;

  $scope.$watch('data', function() {
    MyService.setData($scope.data);
  })
});

app.service('MyService', function() {
  service = {}; // the service object we'll return

  var dataValue = 'data';

  service.setData = function(data) {
    dataValue = data;
  }

  service.getData = function() {
    return dataValue;
  }

  return service;
});

app.filter('truncate', function(MyService) {
  return function(input) {
    return input.substring(0, MyService.getData());
  };
});
```

If you check out the plunk, note that you have to update the text to get the filter to re-run with an updated number of characters to show.

Comment: According to the angular documentation, the #service method will call 'new' on the function it is provided and use that value. How does this correlate to your code that uses #service similar to #factory?

Comment: @IttayD I'm sorry, but I don't know exactly what you are asking about. Perhaps if you provided a link to the passage you refer to or explain more what you are looking for I could explain.  I merely showed you how to use a service to share state between a controller and a filter, which is what I think you were trying to accomplish.  It's hard to tell since your question was pretty brief.

Answer (score 0):

actually this is the way:

Just inject `$filter` to your controller

```
.controller('myController', function($scope, $filter) {...});
```

Then it does not matter where you want to use that filter, just use it like this:

```
$filter('filterName');
```

If you want to pass arguments to that filter, do it using separate parentheses:

```
.controller('myController', function($scope, $filter) {
   $filter('filterName')(argument1,argument2);
});
```